# How to print two aligned columns of text from a list (which may have an odd number of elements) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multiple-columns

I have some code which takes input from the user and stores it in a list. The list may have an odd or even number of elements, for example:
`my_list = ['Beef','Chicken','Eggs','Lamb','Nuts','Pork']` (even number of elements)

or `my_list = ['Beef','Chicken','Eggs','Lamb','Nuts','Pork','Potatoes']` (odd number of elements)

I want to store `my_list` in a string variable, such so that when I `print(var)` or create a tkinter messagebox, my program will output two columns like this:

```
-- Beef       --Chicken
-- Eggs       --Lamb
-- Nuts       --Pork
-- Potatoes
```

I know how to manipulate the strings, but I'm stuck on creating the columns. I have tried this:

```
for x,y in zip(my_list[0::2], my_list[1::2]):
    print("{0} {1}".format(x, y))
```

But that doesn't work for lists of odd-number length.
I have also tried the more complicated:

```
#When my_list = ['Beef','Chicken','Eggs','Lamb','Nuts','Pork','Potatoes']
list1 = []
list2 = []
while len(my_list) != 0:
        list1.append(my_list[0])
        my_list.pop(0)
        if len(my_list) == 0:
            list2.append('')
        else:
            list2.append(my_list[0])
            my_list.pop(0)
    for i in range (len(list1)):
        blank_space = 40 - len(list1[i-1])
        string2 = "\n--" + list1[i] + ' '*blank_space + '--' + list2[i]
        string1 = string1 + string2
    print(string1)
```

but the output I get is like this:

```
--Beef                                --Chicken
--Eggs                                    --Lamb
--Nuts                                    --Pork
--Potatoes                                    --
```

which doesn't align the columns correctly.

Besides splitting it into columns, it is also important that the output is in the form:

```
--Element1    --Element2
--Element3    --Element4
```

and not in any other form. I'd really appreciate any help on where I'm making my mistake. If you need anymore clarification just tell me and I will add it into my question.

**EDIT:**
The function will have to work for all these lists:

```
my_list = ['Beef','Chicken','Eggs','Lamb','Nuts','Pork']
my_list = ['Beef','Chicken','Eggs','Lamb','Nuts','Pork','Potatoes']
my_list = ['Beef','Chicken','Eggs','Lamb','Nuts','Pork','Potatoes','Dairy']
my_list = ['Australian Beef','Chicken','Eggs','Lamb','Nuts','Pork','Potatoes','Dairy']
```

**SECOND EDIT**
I have finally realized why sometimes it doesn't align. The number of spaces is correct, so all of your answers are correct. Unfortunately because some letters are thinner than others, the columns will not be nicely aligned (at least in Python IDLE and Tkinter). For example, `iiii` is shorter than `mmmm` in Python. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: "But that doesn't work for lists of odd-number length." Can you think of a way to tell, ahead of time, whether the length of the list is odd? If you detect this condition, can you think of a way to handle it separately? (Hint: what would happen if you simply removed the last element of the list? If you used your technique for that resulting list, can you think of a simple way to fix that output?)

Comment: "which doesn't align the columns correctly" When you compute the `blank_space` amount, which element of `list1` do you use? On the same time through the loop, which element of `list1` do you pad with the corresponding amount of `blank_space`? Do you see why this causes a problem?

Comment: As an aside, you should try to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) about string formatting in Python. There are powerful tools built-in that mean you don't have to compute the amount of space yourself.

Comment: Thanks for responding @KarlKnechtel, I can detect if a list is odd or even, but I can't remove any elements. I also realised my problem of using `i` in one line and `i+1` in another line, thanks for pointing that out! Unfortunately it still doesn't work after I fixed that. I did research about string formatting, but couldn't apply it successfully

Comment: "but I can't remove any elements." You don't know how to remove an element from a list in Python? How about if you try using a search engine to figure it out? "I did research about string formatting, but couldn't apply it successfully" We can only help you with your attempt if you show it to us (probably as a different question now, with code that focuses on that specific task).

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I must not remove any elements, otherwise my program won't work correctly. That is why when there were an odd number of elements, I added a `''` to make the list even-numbered for splitting it into two columns. I understand that I should make a new question that now targets the specific problem, thanks for all your help.

Comment: What I propose is that, after removing the element and displaying the two-column results for the remainder, you can do a simple additional step to display that last value appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to put it in a comment but it was too long so it became its own answer. To expand on the other answers, I thought it was a good idea to explain what the code is doing.

Breaking up the code into parts, and starting with j1-lee's answer, we have:

```
for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2):
    print(' '.join(f"-- {s:10}" for s in my_list[i:i+2]))
```

or

```
output = '\n'.join(' '.join(f"-- {s:10}" for s in my_list[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2))
```

There are several parts:

- [f-strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) are a handy way of formatting strings. The `f` before the quotes indicates an f-string.
- Within the f-string there is a variable `s` that is part of the list comprehension `for s in my_list[i:i+2]`. `{s:10}` indicates that the length of the string is `10`. (Or you could do something like what Bharel did and have another variable related to the length of the longest string and use that instead of `10`.) This is probably a good idea if you plan to apply it to different lists.
- (f"-- {s:10}" for s in my_list[i:i+2]) creates a generator, for example if you wrote `x = (f"-- {s:10}" for s in my_list[0:0+2])` and then tried `for i in x: print(i)` your output would be two strings: `-- Beef` and `-- Chicken`.
- the `' '.join(...)` joins them together in a list, and like j1-lee says, if you nest them with multiple list comprehensions, you can get a single line.

I think you can probably get the most versatile by combining what j1-lee and Bharel did together. Note that I removed the space in the `join` command since there is now a variable that defines the space between the columns.

```
def generate_columns(list_in, n_columns, column_space, output_as_list = True):
    # Figure our the length of the longest word in the list
    longest_word_length = max(map(len,list_in))
    column_length = longest_word_length + column_space

    output = [''.join([f"-- {s:{column_length}}" \
                       for s in my_list[i:i+n_columns]]) for i in range(0, len(my_list), n_columns)]
    if output_as_list:
        return output
    return '\n'.join(o for o in output)


my_list = ['Beef','Chicken','Eggs','Lamb','Nuts','Pork','Potatoes']

print(generate_columns(my_list, 3, 5))
#['-- Beef         -- Chicken      -- Eggs         ', '-- Lamb         -- Nuts      -- Pork         ', '-- Potatoes     ']
print(generate_columns(my_list, 2, 3, output_as_list = False))
#-- Beef       -- Chicken
#-- Eggs       -- Lamb
#-- Nuts       -- Pork
#-- Potatoes
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation. Unfortunately I encounter another problem when I include another element into `my_list` like so: `my_list = ['Beef','Chicken','Eggs','Lamb','Nuts','Pork','Potatoes','Dairy']`. When I run that list into your function, 'Dairy' does not align correctly, I do not know why.

Comment: I added more information on the kinds of lists I will have to manipulate into my question.

Comment: If the answers provided were correct, as you say, then I think it is fair to mark them as such. It sounds to me like your understanding of the problem has evolved (which is a normal part of learning) and really it's become an issue of understanding alignment in tkinter with different fonts. Maybe you need to build a table to align everything the way you want, maybe it's something else, but perhaps it makes sense to close out this question and ask another refocused question on the issue as it has evolved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have found a work-around by changing the way I present the elements of the list in tkinter. Can you please tell me how to close this question?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following, which uses the fact that out-of-range slicing does not throw an error:

```py
my_list = ['Beef','Chicken','Eggs','Lamb','Nuts','Pork','Potatoes']

for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2):
    print(' '.join(f"-- {s:10}" for s in my_list[i:i+2]))
```

Output:

```
-- Beef       -- Chicken
-- Eggs       -- Lamb
-- Nuts       -- Pork
-- Potatoes
```

Or if you want to get a single string, you can nest `join`:

```py
output = '\n'.join(' '.join(f"-- {s:10}" for s in my_list[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2))
```

Comment: As with the other answers so far provided, I still run into problems if there is another element in the list ex. `my_list = ['Beef','Chicken','Eggs','Lamb','Nuts','Pork','Potatoes','Dairy']` as `Dairy` will not align with `Potatoes`

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go :-)

Variable columns, validates the longest word fits and should be pretty efficient

```
# Figure out the number of columns you wish to have in your table.
COLUMNS = 2

my_list = ['Beef','Chicken','Eggs','Lamb','Nuts','Pork','Potatoes']

# Figure our the length of the longest word in the list
longest_word_length = max(map(len,my_list))

# Create a format string that will add some spacing to the list
format_string = f'-- {{0:{longest_word_length+2}}}'

output = []

# Format all the items in the list
for index, item in enumerate(my_list, start=1):
    output.append(format_string.format(item))
    if index % COLUMNS == 0:
        output.append('\n')

print(''.join(output))
```

You may as well use [tabulate](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate) with the `"plain"` format for an easy way to do it.

Comment: I am still encountering some problems if for example `my_list=['Beef','Chicken','Eggs','Lamb','Nuts','Pork','Potatoes','Dairy']` or `my_list=['Beeeeeeeeeeeef','Chicken','Eggs','Lamb','Nuts','Pork','Potatoes','Dairy']`. Since I cannot control the input (which I'm reading from a file, and the file can change), is there a way to work around the problem?

Comment: I will try to use the tabulate module as you suggested, thanks :)